# When to use do you ever and have you ever?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Do you ever sing a song?
Have you ever sung a song?

In this case, what's the difference between do you ever and have you ever? What's the meaning of do you ever?

Answer (score -1):

**Do you...?** Present Simple tense. 
This question could be asked if you interested does the person do the thing on a regular basis or not.

Do you ever drink coffee after 10 pm?

**Have you...?** Present Perfect tense. 
You can use such a question if asked about previous experiense in someone's life.

Have you ever drunk alcohol?

Comment: can we answer do you ever.. with: no, i don't?

Comment: Well yes. Proper answer for such a question would be Yes, i do/No, i don't.